# Problem with esp8266 and SPI on platformio

Tags: esp8266, spi, platformio, esp-now

I am working with ESP8266 using platformio with arduino-framework using ESP-NOW to drive stepper motors. That works well until I try to use GPIO8 as output for stepper impulses. That is one of the Pins noted for SPI. I do not use SPI. But this setting blocks the loop.
Is there a conflict with ESP-NOW or one with arduino? Is it possible to release the arduino settings for the SPI-pins?

macos 12.5
plaformIO: Core 6.1.c Home 3.4.3

Board: NodeMCU ESP8266 from Joy-it

Includes:

```c
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <espnow.h>
#include "elapsedMillis.h"
```

platformio.ini:

```
[env:nodemcuv2]
platform = espressif8266
board = nodemcuv2
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
upload protocol = esptool
```

Found the solution by reading the right docs:
[https://unsinnsbasis.de/esp8266-pin-belegung/]

The pins I wanted to use are occupied from the system to communicate with the internal flash. They are not usable, but connected to pins on the board(?)

Comment: If you think there's a conflict with ESP-NOW, make a copy of your program, remove everything related to ESP-NOW and try it.

Comment: solution is simple: the GPIO's of the SPI are used internally for the WIFI-Connection and since not usable. I wonder why they are connected to board pins.